# Is there a Sublime Text 2 package for SCM badges, similar to Textmate's ProjectPlus?

Tags: git, sublimetext2, textmate, badge

I'm switching to Sublime Text 2 from Textmate. For the most part I'm finding it an improvement, but I really like having a visual indicator of file status as part of the filename in the gutter. Textmate supports this via ProjectPlus. Is there a similar package for Sublime Text?

Comment: I have to disagree, Textmate (2) is alive and well, I'm getting multiple updates almost daily. dunno about sublime text though, sorry

Comment: Fair enough Kris--I turned off the dev channel some time ago, so my perception may be off. Removed my editorial comment, since it's not germane to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no API to modify (or access in general) the sidebar components, so it is not possible. The closest I have seen is the [Git](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-2-git) plugin, which displays status information in the status bar for the current file.

Comment: I don't know about per-file, but I have [this one](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter) that's per line in the current file. Works pretty well.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy--I have GitGutter installed and find it super useful. Am basically looking for something similar for the sidebar--and as you say, per-file.

Comment: Kris, turns out I was using an ancient Textmate build. Your comment prompted me to try Textmate 2, which contains most of what I like about ProjectPlus and Sublime Text 2, so I'm using that. If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it.